# Powershell: Add-WindowsFeature by pointing script to feature list

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to point to a windows feature list in a script or run a PowerShell command where I would point to a file that contains a list of windows features? for those who use python, i'm inspired by the `pip install -r requirements.txt` method where the requirements.txt just contains a list of packages.

Comment: The `Add-WindowsFeature` cmdlet has a `-ConfigurationFilePath` parameter where you can do as you're asking.  A configuration file can be generated by running `arfw` in `Server Manager`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a list and pass it: `-Name (Get-Content -Path file.txt)` since this parameter can take an array of features.

Comment: But ultimately, you should use something like `DSC` for features since it will keep them enforced.